# Im trying to fill a 2d 20x20 array with the multiplication table of 1 through 20

Tags: c#, arrays

So far I have,

```
int[,] array2d = new int[20, 20];

for (int i = 1; i < array2d.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < array2d.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        array2d[i, j] = i * j ;
        Console.WriteLine(array2d[i, j]);
    }
}
```

but this is skipping some quite a few numbers, I tried to fix it by checking if I is `<=` but that **throws** a `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Is there some point where I made a major error? or is it a simple one.

Comment: Array indicies start at 0.

Comment: I know this but if both values are 0 it populates it with a bunch of 0's first which are not needed

Comment: What numbers does it skip?

Comment: the last number in each sequence so, the first set skips 20 then 40 then  60 etc

Comment: Alright, so again, array indicies start at 0 and therefore end at size-1. You'll never get to index 20 with arrays of size 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are *zero-based* by default; so your array is `[0..19, 0..19]`; however, you want a *different range*: `[1..20, 1..20]`. We should not *mix* them: either (better choice)

```
    int[,] array2d = new int[20, 20];

    // i, j - array indexes
    for (int i = 0; i < array2d.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array2d.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            // since i, j are array indexes we multiply (i + 1) * (j + 1)
            array2d[i, j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);

            Console.Write($"{array2d[i, j],3} ");                
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Or

```
    int[,] array2d = new int[20, 20];

    // i, j are values to be multiplied 
    for (int i = 1; i <= array2d.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= array2d.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            // since i, j are values we have to compute array's indexes: i - 1, j - 1 
            array2d[i - 1, j - 1] = i * j;

            Console.Write($"{array2d[i - 1, j - 1],3} ");                
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: So I tried this but I not quite sure on why it works, more so the Console.Write. Why does that line spit out what is does? What is the $ doing there?

Comment: `$` is *string interpolation*: we put data into `{...}` and it appears within the string, in our case: `$"{array2d[i, j],3} "` it'll be array item; `3` means at least `3` characters, alignend to the right (`-3` if we want align to left).

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] array2d = new int[20, 20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            array2d[i, j] = (i+1) * (j+1) ;
            Console.WriteLine(array2d[i, j]);
        }
    }
```

Your problem was that when you define array like `new int[20]` then it can be iterated from 0 to 19, when you try to acces its value at index 20 you get this exception because index 20 doesnt exist in this array.

When you call arrays .GetLength method it returns its count of fields which is 20, not its maximum index which is 19.